# How can I run a command on all files in a directory and mv to a different the ones that get an output that contains 'Cannot read TIFF header'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, awk

I'd like to remove all bad tiffs from out of a very large directory. The commandline tool "tiffinfo" makes it easy to identify them:

```
tiffinfo -D *
```

This will have an ouput like this:

```
00074000/74986.TIF: Cannot read TIFF header.
```

if the tiff file is corrupt. If this happens I'd like to take the file and move it to a different dirrectory: bad_images. I tried using awk on this, but it hasn't worked so far...
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `Cannot read TIFF header.` message stdout or stderr? Because you may want to say `tiffinfo -D * && echo "it is ok" || echo "lets move it"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "Cannot read TIFF header" error comes on standard error, and assuming `tiffinfo` outputs other data on standard out which you don't want, then:

```
cd /path/to/tiffs
for file in `tiffinfo -D * 2>&1 >/dev/null | cut -f1 -d:`
do
    echo mv $file /path/to/bad_images
done
```

Remove the `echo` to actually move the files, once satisfied that the script will work as expected.